# Rails Minitest BDD Helper Methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm learning Rails and looking to continue to use the spec-style Minitest library https://github.com/metaskills/minitest-spec-rails.

It's pretty straightforward for testing Model validation, and public methods, but I'm a little at a loss for controller testing and route testing.

Where can I find a list of what methods are available for use in my test cases?

Comment: Check out the docs for [ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html) - using minitest-spec is exactly the same as vanilla minitest in this regard.

Comment: @max Thanks Good place to look.